# Can not Install php5.6-gd on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: php

I try to install PHP GD on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.
Looks like I am missing some dependencies:

```
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal /etc/php/5.6/apache2 # apt-get install php5.6-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-4.15.0-60-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.15.0-60 but it is not going to be installed
 php5.6-gd : Depends: php-common (>= 1:73) but 1:55+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
         Depends: php5.6-common (= 5.6.40-30+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 5.6.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
         Depends: libgd3 (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libxpm4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

those are the packages I already have:

```
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal /etc/php/5.6/apache2 # dpkg --get-selections | grep php
libapache2-mod-php5.6               install
php-common                  install
php5.6                      install
php5.6-cli                  install
php5.6-common               install
php5.6-json                 install
php5.6-mbstring             install
php5.6-mcrypt               install
php5.6-mysql                install
php5.6-opcache              install
php5.6-readline             install
php5.6-xml                  install
```

Comment: FYI: If your system is reporting as 16.04.3, you're somewhat behind on updated packages (2+ years, http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/03/03/ubuntu-16-04-4-lts-released/) as it should report 16.04.7 for a fully-upgraded system. Hope your system is off-line.

Comment: Refer prior comment, your system being so *out-of-date* or *unmaintained* could also very much be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get -f install
```

fixed it (facepalm)